# How to queue API calls with 1 second delay in JS using setInterval() inside map() function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function `getData` that fetches a data from an external api. If I make more than 1 request per second, I get 503 error. Hence, I'm thinking to queue API requests, but those calls still get batched altogether and i get same 503 error.

I'm parsing Local Storage data as objects (each object will make a separate API request), and if there is more than 1 object - I want to queue all the subsequent API calls with 1 second delay. Here's my code :

```
const lsData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('weatherappData'));
if (lsData) {
    lsData.map((location, index) => {
        const city = location.city;
        const country = location.country;
        if (index === 0) {
            getData(city, country, table);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => getData(city, country, table), 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map()` does not await the previous `callback`. You can multiply `1000` by `index`

```
setTimeout(() => getData(city, country, table), index * 1000);
```

or use `async/await`.

```
(async() => {
  for (const [index, {city, country}] of lsData.entries()) {
    try {
      if (index === 0) {
        await getData(city, country, table);
      } else {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(getData(city, country, table)), 1000))
      }
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
  }
})()
```

Note, `table` is not defined at the code at the question.